Flutter is there any way that I can get a size like height and width of the unknown Widget from pub dev?
I am using wolt_modal_sheet and tying to make it responsive according to the height. I could get the width using the LayoutBuilder. But the height constraint is returning infinity. I know that I could set the maxHeight but is there any way that I could get the height without setting the maxHeight?
WoltModalSheet.show(
              context: context,
              pageListBuilder: (context) {
                return [
                  WoltModalSheetPage(
                    hasTopBarLayer: false,
                    leadingNavBarWidget: null,
                    trailingNavBarWidget: null,
                    child: Test(),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              pageIndexNotifier: ValueNotifier(0),
              onModalDismissedWithBarrierTap: null,
              onModalDismissedWithDrag: null,
              decorator: null,
              modalTypeBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return WoltModalType.sideSheet();
              },
              transitionAnimationController: null,
              enableDrag: true,
              showDragHandle: false,
              useSafeArea: false,
            );

This is just one example but other things as well. I tried to get the parent widget's height and width, however, I could not find the way to do it.

If you need to get the width of the screen , you can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.width to get the width.
But , Inn addtion you can use FractionallySizedBox alternatively to specify a percentage of the available space to fill


 FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.5,
    heightFactor: 0.5,
    child: (..your widget..);
),




I know how to get the width and height of the screen but i wanted to get the width and height of the parent widgets. I am using packages and I can't get the exact width to adjust the size.
